# How to temporarily increase the speed of a character in a Unity game

Tags: unity

As the title would suggest, I want to give a character a speed boost for x amount of seconds, while increasing their Gameobject's mass. During this little speed boost, I also want to add a script to another player that disappears when the speed boost dies out I am new to C#, and Unity in general, any help would be appreciated.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerAddMass : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
        {
            rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            rb.mass = 10;
            rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            rb.speed = 5;
        }
    }
}
```

The code above was found on a unity website of some sorts, and I modified it to set the speed and mass numbers (I changed the 0s into a 10 and a 5) The errors I get are "rb does not exist in the current context" x 4

Comment: What did you try so far? There are lots of Unity scripting tutorials you can find that show how to move a character using a speed variable, or triggering changes based on elapsed time. Show us the code you're using now, based on the research you've put in so far. How does this code depart from what you want it to do?

Comment: I added the code

Comment: use coroutines for this

Comment: Hmmm... Rigidbody doesn't have a property called `speed` — did you mean to manipulate its `velocity` instead? Where are you trying to return the velocity to normal after the end of the boost duration?

Comment: Yea, I want it to activate for 10 seconds, then go back to normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a quick test for boosting player speed.

When your player is moving and you press "B" player speed will be boosted for "boostTime " with the speed of "boostIncrease". I hope it works for you.

You just attach the script to the player and you are ready to go. By the way using "GetComponent" in update is not a good idea so pleas avoid it as much as possible.

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    [RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
    public class TemporarySpeedBoost : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private Rigidbody rb;

        [Header("Player movement Settings")]
        [SerializeField] private float steadySpeed = 5.0f;

        [Space(10)]
        [SerializeField] private float boostIncrease = 5.0f;
        [SerializeField] private float boostTime = 10.0f;

        private bool isBoostActivated = false;

        void Start()
        {
            if (rb == null)
            {
                rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            }
        }

        void Update()
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
            {
                rb.mass = 10;
                if (isBoostActivated)
                {
                    rb.velocity = transform.forward * (steadySpeed + boostIncrease);
                }
                else
                {
                    rb.velocity = transform.forward * steadySpeed;
                }
            }

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.B))
            {
                if (!isBoostActivated)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Boosting player speed");
                    isBoostActivated = true;
                    Invoke("EndBoost", boostTime);
                }
            }
            Debug.Log(rb.velocity);
        }

        private void EndBoost()
        {
            isBoostActivated = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The Q button activates the boost?

Comment: "Q" is used to move you player with normal speed while B is for Boost.
Boost will only work if you are pressing down "Q"

Comment: It didn't provide a noticeable speed increase. Do I need to change settings?

Comment: Yes you can change settings from unity. change the value of  "Boost increase" to what ever value you want i currently set it to 5. And also  set the "Angular drag" in the rigid body to 0.